# Tkinter: Extend labels to the edge of the column

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to set up a three-column table with Python and Tkinter. For this purpose, I implement each cell both as a canvas and as a label inside the canvas because I need the tags option of the canvas widget.

I want to spread each cell over the whole width of the column from left to right (so that click events can be recorded not only on the text but on the whole row). However, the following code does not do this:

The text is centered but the labels and canvases only include the text, not the whole width of the cell. I tried adding

```
sticky = Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S+Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W
```

on the labels and/or the canvases; however, with some combinations, the text is aligned left and each label and canvas only includes the text instead of the whole cell, with others the sticky attribute the text is again centered but the labels and canvases are still narrow.

This is my code:

```
import Tkinter

class Application(Tkinter.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master.geometry("800x600")
        self.grid()

        list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7777, 8888, 9999]]

        self.cells_canvas = []
        self.cells_label = []
        i = 0

        for entry in list:
            self.cells_canvas.append([Tkinter.Canvas(self), Tkinter.Canvas(self), Tkinter.Canvas(self)])
            self.cells_label.append([None, None, None])

            self.cells_label[i][0] = Tkinter.Label(self.cells_canvas[i][0])
            self.cells_label[i][0]["text"] = entry[0]
            self.cells_label[i][0].config(bg = "#A00")
            self.cells_label[i][0].grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 1) # reference A
            self.cells_canvas[i][0].grid(row = i, column = 0, columnspan = 1) # reference B

            self.cells_label[i][1] = Tkinter.Label(self.cells_canvas[i][1])
            self.cells_label[i][1]["text"] = entry[1]
            self.cells_label[i][1].grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 1)
            self.cells_canvas[i][1].grid(row = i, column = 1, columnspan = 1)

            self.cells_label[i][2] = Tkinter.Label(self.cells_canvas[i][2])
            self.cells_label[i][2]["text"] = entry[2]
            self.cells_label[i][2].grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 1)
            self.cells_canvas[i][2].grid(row = i, column = 2, columnspan = 1)

            i = i+1

root = Tkinter.Tk()
app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

With this code, only the text in column 0 but not the whole columns appears with red background.
With adding sticky = Tkinter.N+Tkinter.S+Tkinter.E+Tkinter.W at reference A nothing changes.
With adding that at code B, the text appears aligned left. Again, only the text has red beackground.
With that code at references A and B, the same.

Comment: as your table seems to be readonly (using labels not entrys) is there any reason why you couldn't use multiple listboxes that scroll together?

Comment: please create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are right. I changed the code accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `grid`, the `sticky` option is indeed how you get a label to fill its cell. The label widget has an `anchor` option which controls where the text appears within the label.

In addition, you have to make sure that in a given parent, the column(s) expand to fill any extra space in the parent. In your case, column 0 in the canvas is only as wide as its contents, so it doesn't fill the full width of the canvas.

You need to give column 0 in each canvas a positive weight so the column will expand to fill the space given to it.

```
self.cells_canvas[i][0].columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
self.cells_canvas[i][1].columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
self.cells_canvas[i][2].columnconfigure(2, weight=1)
```

You'll probably want to do a similar thing with each row. A very good rule of thumb when using a canvas is to always make sure at least one row and at least one column have a positive weight.

If you only have one widget in each canvas, `pack` is probably the better choice since you don't have to worry about color and rows.

Comment: The label itself sticks to the left side of the canvas (in those cases where the canvas spreads over the whole column) and stays narrow - even if I add the sticky attribute. I can make that visible by adding a background (self.cells_label[i][1].config(bg="#A00")). The background of the label is only as wide as the text.

Comment: @MichaelWestwort: I've updated my answer. The short answer is, the label _is_ expanding to fill its column. However, the column is _not_ expanding to fill its parent.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. By the way, Entry instead of Label does it right even without sticky.

Comment: @MichaelWestwort: no, Entry is no different than Label. It may seem like it's working, but it's only because they default to a similar size so all of the widgets in a column will be the same width and appear to fill. If you change some other parameters that causes the columns to be wider you'll see the very same program.